# How to match and delete an element from a queue?

Tags: system-verilog

According to [1800-2012 specs](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf),

```
Queue::delete( [input int index] )
```

deletes an element of a queue in SystemVerilog, furthermore, a Queue can perform the same operations as an unpacked Array, giving it access to:

```
Array::find_first_index( )
```

which returns the index of the first element matching a certain criteria. i.e.

```
find_first_index( x ) with ( x == 3)
```

Now I'd like to delete a unique item, guaranteed to exist, from the Queue. Combining 1 and 1 gives me:

```
queue.delete(queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == obj_to_del ));
```

The compiler does not appreciate that though saying that the argument passed must be either an integer or integer compatible. I could probably pull the two apart:

```
int index = queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == obj_to_del );
queue.delete( index );
```

or force an integer by typecasting find_first_index:

```
queue.delete(int'(queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == obj_to_del ))) //Just finished compiling, does not work.
```

The former does not look very elegant to me, and the latter seems somewhat forced which made me curious if there is maybe a more proper way to accomplish this. Is find_first_index possibly returning an array of size one with the index at location 0?

EDIT: I foolishly did not provide a self contained example: A stripped example of what I'm doing looks like:

```
class parent_task;
endclass;

class child_taskA extends parent_task;
endclass;

class child_taskB extends parent_task;
endclass;    

class task_collector;

 child_taskA A_queue[$];
 child_taskB B_queue[$];

 function delete_from_queue(parent_task task_to_del);
      case (task_to_del.type):
         A: A_queue.delete(A_queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == task_to_del));
         B: B_queue.delete(B_queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == task_to_del));
         default: $display("This shouldn't happen.");
 endfunction
endclass
```

The error message, word for word is:

```
Error-[SV-IQDA] Invalid Queue delete argument
"this.A_queue.find_first_index( iterator ) with ((iterator == task))"
 Queue method delete can take optional integer argument. So, argument passed
 to it must be either integer or integer assignment compatible.
```

There are checks in place to make sure that the task in question exists before the call to delete_from_queue.

Comment: From further analysis it does indeed look like find_first_index returns an array.

`int index = queue.find_first_index( x ) where (x == obj_to_del );`

complains about assigning an int$[$] to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
queue.delete(int'(queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == obj_to_del )));
```

works for me. It would really help if you could provide complete self contained examples like the one below:

```
module top;
   int queue[$] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   let object_to_del = 3;
       initial begin
      queue.delete(int'(queue.find_first_index( x ) with ( x == object_to_del )));
      $display("%p", queue);
       end
endmodule
```

But what if there was no match? Would you not need to test the result from find_first_index() anyways before deleting?

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. I have added a contained example above. There are checks in place before the call to the delete function and I am confident that this particular delete will only be called if the item in question exists.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the latter version using the int'() cast works for me.

Comment: Mh... My compiler is not happy with the typecast:  '[IMEMCT] Invalid memory usage. Memory or memory slice is not permitted to be used in following context: /* omitted */  Expression : this.A_queue.find_first_index( )' Strange... I'll do the roundabout way of first finding the index and storing it in an int, then report back.

Comment: From your comment this does seem to be a compiler issue then. I'm not sure if I might have to specifically flag that i'm using sverilog or what's causing the error.  I'll consider this question settled until I figure it out.

Comment: The array search methods such as find_first_index are defined to return a queue of values. This definition is valuable even for the "first" methods, because it allows them to return an empty result. I don't see any evidence in the LRM that it's legal to cast a queue, even a 1-element queue, to a value of its element type. So it seems to me that the int' cast that Dave reports as working must be a non-standard (albeit somewhat convenient) vendor extension, and the error that Jan reports is in fact exactly what you should expect.

Comment: Oh, mea culpa. It *is* legal to cast a queue-of-int to int. It's a "bit-stream cast" (1800-2012 clause 6.24.3). The cast should throw a runtime error if the queue doesn't have exactly one element, and yield the expected result if there's exactly one element.

Comment: This is quite odd. All the major simulators support bit-stream cast in simple cases, but just one of them gives the error Jan reported. However, this rather forced example *does* work in that tool (I'm not recommending it, just noting with curiosity that it compiles and runs correctly):
    int indexQ[$];
    que.delete(int'((indexQ = que.find_first_index(x) with (...))));

Answer (score 1):

The int cast didn't work for me as well but the following worked

```
int index_to_del[$];

index_to_del = que.find_first_index(x) with ( x == task_to_del );
que.delete(index_to_del[0]);
```