# delete queue items inside foreach loop

Tags: system-verilog

When we need to delete some items inside a queue, we may easily write code like below:

```
foreach(queue[i]) begin
    if(queue[i].value == 1)
         queue.delete(i);
end
```

But there is bugs in above code when queue[0]==queue[1]==1. Because queue.delete(0) will change all indexes of items inside queue.

So currently I use code as below:

```
foreach(queue[i]) begin
    if(queue[i].value == 1) begin
         queue.delete(i);
         i--;
    end
end
```

It works, but it looks confusing at first glance.

So my question is: 
Are there any better solution for this issue in system verilog?

Comment: The solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494550/how-to-match-and-delete-an-element-from-a-queue) doesn't work for me. A similar solution can be implemented using a `repeat` loop: `repeat(q.size()) begin if(q[i]==1) q.delete(i);i++; end`. Note that the iterator in `repeat` loop is constant even it the size of queue changes.

Comment: @sharvil111 There was a typo in my original question. I have modified it and now it should work.

Comment: I have pointed out to a similar question in my previous comment. Here's plain link for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494550/how-to-match-and-delete-an-element-from-a-queue

Comment: @sharvil111 I got error with your solution repeat loop _** Error: a.sv(23): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'i'._ My tool is questa

Comment: First **define** the variable `i` and initialize to 0. Please don't blindly copy-paste the codes from anywhere.

Comment: @sharvil111 I still got wrong result with your solution. I think what you mean is `repeat(q.size()) begin if(q[i]==1) q.delete(i); else i++; end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129958/discussion-between-sharvil111-and-awill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work (I'm unable to test it right now. Make sure order is persevered when you try it out)

```
queue = queue.find() with ( item.value != 1 );
```

Another approach would be to find all the indexes that meet your criteria, sort in depending order, then loop through the indexes

```
int qi[$] =  queue.find_index() with ( item.value == 1 );
qi = qi.sort() with ( -item ); // sort highest to lowest 
foreach(qi[idx]) queue.delete(qi[idx]);
```

Refer to [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.12 *Array manipulation methods* for details